# Is exclamation mark lower priority than method calls and properties access in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

When negating expressions using the exclamation mark, I always use parenthesis to keep on the safe side... But I did some tests and it looks like exclamation mark operator's priority is low enough to make parenthesis unnecessary in most use cases, namely function calls and property access :

```
!(myFunction());        // can be replaced by !myFunction()
!(myObject.myProperty); // can be replaced by !myObject.myProperty
```

Is that correct ? Is it good practice to use parenthesis anyway ?

Comment: [MDN: Operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table).

Comment: Enclosing brackets makes sense only in `!(firstFn() && secondFn())` kind of situations, for precedence two or more operators are required.

Comment: just test it, if it works once in a certain way, it will work always and everywhere the same way (at least as far as parens are concerned)

Comment: @dandavis, this is a truly terrible advice.

Comment: @Kay: how so? JS is like math, consistent and repeatable. if a paren usage is not a syntax error in IE, it won't be one in firefox. if it has no effect now, it will not have an effect later...

Comment: @dandavis, you know that because you had many years of algebra is school. There is a given ruleset, the operator precedence, which should be looked up in a normative resource, not be divined by the user.

Comment: specifically to parens, i guess had a secret weapon while learning: old firefox. in versions before, say 10, the JS parser would parse function body text into the "correct" syntax, so that `alert(function(){return (3)+(2);})` would show `function(){return 3+2;}` i miss the old parsed code, but comments are nice to be able to reach from JS, so it's a tradeoff. anyway, old firefox will tell you the "right" way of coding everything, making the firebug command line informative and authoritative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like operator precedence (a fundamental part of any language) your best bet is usually to consult the documentation, e.g.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

rather than doing a bunch of tests. Tests are important to verify the runtime behavior, but trying to empirically determine operator precedence can get complex: there are a *lot* of operators!

To really understand how operator precedence works, we have to know a bit about how Javascript code gets transformed from source, and ultimately executed.

(In general, this depends on the JS runtime you're using (e.g. V8, or WebKit's JavaScriptCore). I'm not an expert in such things, so this is a high level overview of how you can generally expect things to work.)

The first step in the process involves *parsing* the syntax of your source code, and transforming it into an *abstract syntax tree* composed of *tokens*, or individual identifiers in your code. These are the 'building blocks' of the low-level interactions in your code.

To look at your first example specifically (omitting the parentheses), we have:

```
!myFunction();
```

There are four tokens in the source: `!`, `myFunction`, `()`, and `;`. We can determine the order these tokens will be combined by reading the operator precedence chart from top to bottom. (According to the chart, `;` is not an operator).

"Function Call" has the highest precedence, so we can write the expression as

```
!(myFunction());
```

since the "Function Call" operator (`()`) will 'bind' to the `myFunction` identifier before the `!` operator.

Similarly, for your second example (again, omitting the parentheses):

```
!myObject.myProperty;
```

We have the tokens `!`, `myObject`, `.`, `myProperty`, and `;`. Reading down the chart, we see that "Member Access" (`.`) has a higher precedence (18) than "Logical NOT" (15), so this expression is equivalent to

```
!(myObject.myProperty);
```

If the precedence order were reversed for these two operators, we'd instead have

```
(!myObject).myProperty;
```

To address your question about conventions: ultimately, we can simply write `!myObject.myProperty;`, (as most JS programmers do) because we intuitively expect property access to have a higher precedence than logical negation.

When to include parentheses is largely a matter of taste, and you will need to develop good judgement as to when it's justified. If we used parentheses 100% or 0% of the time we had a choice, our code would be unreadable. There's a middle path somewhere in between, and the best way to pick this up is to read a lot of JS code, and develop an intuitive sense for the conventions of the community. When you're starting out, it never hurts to err on the side of more parentheses; once you develop expertise, you will probably favor a more terse coding style.

Comment: the dot is an operator.

Comment: The parens are also operators.

Comment: @Kay Thanks! I updated my answer. I am on somewhat shaky ground here (not an expert on ECMAScript parsing rules) in terms of my knowledge; ideally someone could edit my answer for correctness.